# How to write helm hook to delete persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, zeebe

I am new to k8s and helm. I am deploying an [open source distributed software called zeebe](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/platform-deployment/helm-kubernetes/deploy/) that provides helm charts for k8s deployment. I have seen that even after executing the `helm uninstall` command the persistent volume claims and persistent volumes do not get deleted.

A workaround is stated on [this helm github issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5156#issuecomment-812695838) to define a helm hook. Being new to helm I cannot find an example to try this out. The only file that I have been editing so far when [installing](https://helm.camunda.io/#installing-charts) and uninstalling helm chart is the values.yaml file. Kindly guide me on how and where to write an helm hook for zeebe deployment to delete its persistent volumes on `helm uninstall`.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd add the hook Job to a file in the chart's `templates` directory, like any other Kubernetes resource.  Note that, if the PVC is indirectly created through a StatefulSet, Helm may not have direct knowledge of it.  Is there a specific problem you're running into with this setup?  What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. All pv and pvc could be deleted through
`kubectl delete pvc -l app=camunda-platform` command